# Spring Webservices: Error in WSDL ("use" attribute of soap:body empty)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a question on WSDL generation with DefaultWsdl11Definition from Spring Webservices 1.5:

There is a set of abount 50 webservice methods and its request and response types. In  I see, that the "use" attribute of "" is empty.

```
<wsdl:operation name="SuspiciousOperation">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input name="SuspiciousOperationRequest">
        <soap:body use=""/>                               <!-- here is the error! -->
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="SuspiciousOperationResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

This leads to an error in the clients.

Here is the fragement of the XSD file defining the request and response types:

```
<xs:element name="SuspiciousOperationRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="someID" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="SuspiciousOperationResponse">
    <xs:complexType />
</xs:element>
```

Can someone explain, what causes this error?

Best regards,

Markus

Comment: Can you show the XSD schema's you used to generate this WSDL?

Comment: I added the fragement of the XSD file, that defines both types.

Answer (score 0):

Strange... Restarting the servlet container fixed the bug...

Does DefaultWsdl11Definition some kind of caching?